# Sending files via bluetooth depending on rssi value

Tags: python, python-2.7, bluetooth, pybluez

I am scanning nearby bluetooth devices. And I have dictionary with MAC address and rssi value like this:

`dictionary = {"18:FF:E3:3B:5D:31": "-49","11:11:11:3B:5D:31": "-60", }`

In this case I would like to send file to 18:FF:E3:3B:5D:31 only when rssi is bigger than -50. 
What is the best way to do  that?
While loop depending on MAC address?
The list of trusted MAC address will be known. It could be more devices to send files with different rssi.

it is just an idea:

```
scan for devices
while i < 100 // random number  
    for key, val  in dictionary.iteritems():
        if key == mac_address_of_one_device and rssi > 50:
            send_file()
        else:
            scan again 
        // some kind of recursion?
```

But what if I have 2 devices at the same time in range and I want to send file to two devices. How to scan it?

**Or how to scan let's say for 1 minut and depending on rssi and MAC sending file to devices which is in range?**

I am stucked.

Comment: At first you should get the syntax of your script right.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good practice to scan device everytime, since you are trying to send file based on rssi signal.

The scan timeout is specific to bluetooth stack. most bluetooth stack will have a default timeout of 15 to 30 seconds(to conserve power),

During the scan process, you will get the list of nearby bluetooth device address as well as RSSI information in the inquiry result/complete event(event from BT HCI signalling device found.). You can iterate through the results and send file to the devices having RSSI greater than -50 or any other value.

But the question here is whether the remote device has the capability to receive file? I dont see that you are checking it  here. Just by having the bluetooth address and RSSI does not guarantee that the remote device will accept your file.

Comment: Thank you for an answear. I will try the way you suggest.

Regarding to the capability to receive file I do this check in other method. And I am able to get info if I can or I can not send a file. But thank you for paying attention.